# How to remove specific element from array with RactiveJs

Tags: ractivejs

I need to remove a specific element from the array (either by index or by object itself - doesn't matter). Seems like I'm blind but I don't see appropriate method in RactiveJs documentation. I found a method to remove an element from the beginning of the arrya (shift) or from the end of the array (pop) but don't see a method to remove specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [`ractive.splice`](https://ractive.js.org/v0.x/0.8/ractive-splice)

```
ractive.splice('myArray', indexToRemove, 1)
```

is the way to go.

Comment: Yep, [docs here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-splice) - you can actually just ignore the `add` parameters altogether, as in `ractive.splice('myArray', indexToRemove, 1)`

Comment: How can an instance figure out its own index in the array, so that it can remove itself from the array? The only way I've found is to get the indexOf the instance's own _guid in the array's _guids, but the underscore suggests that one shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Define *index reference* on list (the *num* in below example) and then use `splice`:

```
{{#each students:num}}
    <p>{{firstName}}</p>
    <button on-click="event.splice('..', event.get('num'), 1)">Remove</button>
{{/each}
```